# How do I focus on an input inside a table cell?

Tags: jquery, excel, datatables

I have inputs inside my table cells

```
<td alt="" class="timesheet-highlight"><input type="text" id="C6R1" name="C6R1" size="7" value="0.00" class="form-control"></td>
```

When I tab onto the table cell it applied the class `timesheet-highlight`. What I am having trouble figuring out is how to focus the input that is inside the cell.  There are multiple inputs in the table and the ID's are generated dynamically so there is no way to know what it will be.  Some cells may not have any inputs.

I can fire an event when I tab onto the cell with this

```
.on('key-focus', function (e, datatable, cell) {
    if ($('td').hasClass('timesheet-highlight')) {
        alert('hi');
    }                
});
```

I am using Datatables and this is my full code to generate said table:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var grid = $('#tblTimeSheet').DataTable({
            "scrollY": "567px",
            "paging": false,
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            keys: {
                className: 'timesheet-highlight'
            }
        });
        grid
        .on('key-focus', function (e, datatable, cell) {
            if ($('td').hasClass('timesheet-highlight')) {
                alert('hi');
            }

        });
        /*.on('key-blur', function (e, datatable, cell) {
            $('#details').html('No cell selected');
        });*/
    });
```

Comment: `$('td.timesheet-highlight > input').focus();` ???

Comment: Never thought of that. Thank you.

Comment: I think you should use instead `cell` but as i don't know this plugin, not sure what object it is but if already a jq object, it would be: `cell.children('input').focus();`

Answer (score 0):

The .on('key-focus'.... function has the cell parameter which is the cell on which the focus is currently on.

by invoking cell.node() you get the 'td' element
So if I understand you correctly, what you want is this:

```
.on('key-focus', function (e, datatable, cell) {
   var inputFieldInSelectedTd = $(cell.node()).find('input');
   if (inputFieldInSelectedTd) {
      inputFieldInSelectedTd.focus();
   }
});
```